# Blank page showing. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, exception

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 93600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M'); 

require str_replace('importers', '', dirname(__FILE__)) . 'app/Mage.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {

$app = Mage::app('default');
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-100 days'));

 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

echo $orders->getSelect();
//print_r($orders);

}  catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    echo "Some Error Occurred";
}
```

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the following line of code:

```
require str_replace('importers', '', dirname(__FILE__)) . 'app/Mage.php';
```

Please try to use the below code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 93600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M'); 

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {

$app = Mage::app('default');
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-100 days'));

 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

echo $orders->getSelect();
//print_r($orders);

}  catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    echo "Some Error Occurred";
}
```